# How can I stop text from making my round button into an oval?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm using Pug and CSS to make a round button which looks like this without any text in it:

[image: no text round button]

This is the code I used

```
button(class="round-button")

.round-button {border: none; padding: 40px; border-radius: 1000px; }
```

This looks nice **without** text. If I add text, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I keep my button circular while it has text in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use border-radius: 50%.

Height and width also need to be the same.

```css
.round-button {
border: none; 
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
border-radius: 50%; 
background-color: pink;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="round-button">text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need just a `fixed-height`specially when your text's length is dynamic,if you use padding it wouldn't be round.

```
   .round-button
    {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial mockup, you have an 80px by 80px circle. If you know your text will fit into it, consider doing the following:

```
.round-button {
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This turns the padding to 0. The `line-height` forces the height of the circle. The width forces the width. You can leave the border-radius as you have it, or do 50% as others have mentioned.

The downside of this is that if the text renders large, it may overflow the boundary of your circle.

Answer (score 0):

The **width** and **height** must have the **same** **length**.

If you **don't** **know** the width and height (no CSS declaration), you have to use **JavaScript**. Select all buttons. Loop through the buttons, measure the width and set the height with the measured width.

#### Example

```js
function El(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

function getCSS(el, value) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(value);
}

var roundButtons = El(".round-button");

roundButtons.forEach(function(roundButton) {
  var width = getCSS(roundButton, "width");
  roundButton.style.height = width;
});
```

```css
.round-button {
  border: none;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="round-button">Button</button>
<button class="round-button">Button 2</button>
<button class="round-button">Another rounded square button</button>
```